# Swift "Ambiguous use of" when adding a neutral generic parameter

Tags: swift, generics, overloading, swift5

When I write:

```swift
public func perform() async throws -> Int {
   fatalError()
}

public func perform<Output: Decodable>() async throws -> Output {
    fatalError()
}

public func doIt() async throws -> Int {
    try await perform()
}
```

Everything is ok.

But when I write:

```swift
public func perform<Input: Encodable>(body: Input) async throws -> Int {
   fatalError()
}

public func perform<Input: Encodable, Output: Decodable>(body: Input) async throws -> Output {
    fatalError()
}

public func doIt<Input: Encodable>(body: Input) async throws -> Int {
    try await perform(body: body)
}
```

Then I've got the "Ambiguous use of 'perform(body:)'" error on the `try await perform(body: body)` call.

I'm trying to understand why this is. I get that `Int` conforms to `Decodable` and that may cause the ambiguity. But then I wonder why in my first example that doesn't happen. I suspect that the introduction of another generic type make the election of candidate functions behave differently, even if that type isn't involved in the ambiguity at all.

Is that so ?
As a bonus: could anyone point out an entry point to Swift doc / source code involved in this selection process?

Note: I'm not looking for workarounds, already got this addressed, I'm just trying to understand the underlying mechanisms.

Comment: `Input` in `doIt` and `Input` in `perform` have the same name but are two different generic types. You could make the enclosing struct or class generic and remove the generic declaration from the methods.

Comment: Thanks @vadian but I'm not looking for a workaround.